# Create from scratch HttpServletRequestWrapper and HttpServletResponseWrapper objects

Tags: scala, servlets

I am trying to write `Scala` unit tests for a servlet. I want to use `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and `HttpServletResponseWrapper` objects for that, but the only constructor must receive `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`. Even If I create new class:

```
public class testRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

}
```

Then the constructor must call super constructor with `HttpServletRequest` object.

I am trying to "break to loop" and find how to instantiate a request from scratch, without a given request/response. How can I do that? create request/response?

Comment: Why you don't want to use mocks for `HttpServletRequestWrapper` or for `HttpServletRequest` that is required to construct former?

Comment: Also take a look at Spring's [MockHttpServletRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html)